# Resource temporarily unavailable when building dotnet core 3.0 dependency on ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, asynchronous, .net-core

I have a .net core 3.0 project which I'm trying to dockerise. The project file called `SuperSecretProject.csproj` is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>SuperSecretProject.Program</StartupObject>
    <UserSecretsId>cee96675-39d5-486b-bcca-9db409d1d0c4</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.9.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The docker file is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS debug

WORKDIR /build-debug
COPY ./SuperSecretProject.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "hello"]
```

However, when building, I got the `Resource temporarily unavailable.` E.g.
`docker build -f ./docker/Dockerfile . -t test` gives:

```
Step 4/5 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in d4ca119fa22c
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions/index.json'.
  Resource temporarily unavailable
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading.tasks.extensions/index.json'.
  Resource temporarily unavailable
....
```

A bit of research shows that docker has a limit on number of Tasks that it can run: https://success.docker.com/article/how-to-reserve-resource-temporarily-unavailable-errors-due-to-tasksmax-setting 
But this fix does not seem to work.

NOTE: I can successfully build the docker image if step 4 is changed into `dotnet restore --disable-parallel` but for bigger projects, the build time becomes too long. It would be nice if all the `async` tasks in `dotnet restore` could be done in parallel.

Comment: Try running docker build with `--network=host`, like `docker build --network=host -f ./docker/Dockerfile . -t test`

Comment: it worked for me setting --network=bridge, however... I don't understand the reason

Answer (score 0):

Restart docker daemon helps.

For reference:
https://forums.docker.com/t/dotnet-restore-fails-when-building-in-docker-container/95386